# How to resolve "Exited with return code 1. Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException" error?

Tags: java

Im brand new to coding and I just made this account a few minutes ago because I'm having a lot of trouble with this problem.

Write a method so that the main() code below can be replaced by simpler code that calls method calcMilesTraveled(). Original main():

```
public class CalcMiles {
   public static void main(String [] args) {
      double milesPerHour = 70.0;
      double minutesTraveled = 100.0;

      double hoursTraveled;
      double milesTraveled;

      hoursTraveled = minutesTraveled / 60.0;
      milesTraveled = hoursTraveled * milesPerHour;

      System.out.println("Miles: " + milesTraveled);
   }
}
```

Above is the question being asked, and below is my response

```
public double calcMilesTraveled(double milesPerHour, double minTraveled){
    
   Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

  double minsTraveled;
    minsTraveled = scnr.nextDouble();
   
   double hoursTraveled;
   hoursTraveled = minsTraveled / 60.0;
   
   return milesPerHour * hoursTraveled;
}
```

When I execute the program I get the "Exited with return code 1.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException" error. The program runs fine when I manually input the variables but to answer the question it must allow any variable.

```
'Exited with return code 1. Exception in thread "main"
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
at main$CalcMiles.calcMilesTraveled(main.java:428)
at main.main(main.java:445)'
```

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace of that error you are getting.

Comment: My bad I'm still getting used to this. Here you go.                                                 
'Exited with return code 1.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
 at main$CalcMiles.calcMilesTraveled(main.java:428)
 at main.main(main.java:445)'

Comment: In addition to above comment, add how exactly you call the new method(updated main method).

Comment: It seems to work fine for me when there is an open input stream. This error indicates there isn't one. However, I don't think you meant to have the minutes traveled both be passed as a parameter to the function and gotten from user input in the same function. I think what you meant is to replace `scnr.nextDouble()` with `minTraveled` which will also fix your problem.

Comment: @Jesse this worked, Thank you very much. Thank you to everyone else too, I know I messed up a little bit making the post but the pointers are much appreciated

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "...but to answer the question it must allow any variable."?

Answer (score -2):

The boolean return method you wrote has to be *static* in order to be called.
**Code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalcMiles {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        double milesPerHour = 70.0;
        double minutesTraveled = 100.0;

        double hoursTraveled;
        double milesTraveled;

        hoursTraveled = minutesTraveled / 60.0;
        milesTraveled = hoursTraveled * milesPerHour;

        System.out.println("Miles: " + milesTraveled + "\n");

        System.out.println("Miles: " + calcMilesTraveled(milesPerHour, minutesTraveled));
    }
    public static double calcMilesTraveled(double milesPerHour, double minTraveled){

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        double minsTraveled;
        minsTraveled = scnr.nextDouble();

        double hoursTraveled;
        hoursTraveled = minsTraveled / 60.0;

        return milesPerHour * hoursTraveled;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I am on Java version 17.

Comment: The error provided does not indicate in any way that this is the problem. The error for calling a non-static method from a static context is a syntax error, meaning it wouldn't even run. The error the OP posted indicates that not only does it run, but it attempts to run `scnr.nextDouble()` which is 3 lines into the method.